# Can't enable Cloud Build API (or any other) due missing permission. But what role contains the needed permission?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-iam

I want to create my Cloud Build API but I have not the proper permission. I know how to add permissions and am able to add roles to my IAM however the error message leaves me clueless in what permission I actually need or what role holds that permission.

[image]

These are my current roles:

- Service Account Key Admin
- Organization Administrator
- Project IAM Admin

Can someone give me the role or permission name so I can look it up?

Answer (score 0):

Following the [official IAM documentation on Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/iam-roles-permissions), I think that the role of ***roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor*** could serve you well, since it grants full control of Cloud Build resources. Even though you have set the correct IAM permissions, you need to specify an specific role for this API. Please, tell me if this has helped you.

Comment: added the `Cloud Build Editor` role but the problem still remains

Comment: Could you please verify that the role is enabled? Here's the link that shows how to do so https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account#granting_a_role_using_the_settings_page

Comment: I just went with the `Editor` role now. I know it has a lot of permission excesses but I really haven't the nerves to figure out every single permission just to activate a simple API :D

Comment: Then you should try the role roles/owner, which provides full control over all resources within a project. You should be able to do so, since you're your own organization administrator. If this works better for you, I'll edit my comment to give a full response on this.

Comment: @xetra11 does it answers your question ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Editor` role seems to contain the needed permission. However it has a lot of excess permissions so it's not the perfect solution